# Adding page numbers in a text from a PDF file in Python

Tags: python, pdf, text

The following Python program reads a PDF file and collects unique words used in that file.

```
import PyPDF2
import re

print('process started')

pdfFile = open('pdf_file.pdf', 'rb')
pdfFileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pdfFilePageCount = pdfFileReader.numPages

pdfPageText = ""
for i in range(pdfFilePageCount):
    pageObj = pdfFileReader.getPage(i)
    pdfPageText += pageObj.extractText()

pdfPageText = pdfPageText.lower()
pdfPageText = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', pdfPageText)
listOfWords = pdfPageText.split()

setPage = set(listOfWords)  

textFile = open('text_file.txt', 'w')
for item in listOfWords:
  textFile.write("%s\n" % item)

textFile.close()
pdfFile.close()
print('process ended')
```

Is it possible to add page numbers with each word (i.e. to indicate from which page they were picked)?

For instance, if a word "xyzabc" is found in multiple pages, I need to list them all as follows:

```
xyzabc (1,22,130, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict whose keys are the words, and values a list of page numbers.

Using a `defaultdict` makes it easy to append the page numbers.

You also have to update the dict in each loop, as shown in the modified code here:

```
import PyPDF2
import re
from collections import defaultdict

print('process started')

pdfFile = open('pdf_file.pdf', 'rb')
pdfFileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pdfFilePageCount = pdfFileReader.numPages

wordsAndPages = defaultdict(list)

pdfPageText = ""
for page in range(pdfFilePageCount):
    pageObj = pdfFileReader.getPage(page)
    pdfPageText = pageObj.extractText()
    print(pdfPageText)
    pdfPageText = pdfPageText.lower()
    pdfPageText = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', pdfPageText)
    listOfWords = pdfPageText.split()

    for word in listOfWords:
        wordsAndPages[word].append(page)


textFile = open('text_file.txt', 'w')
for word, pages in wordsAndPages.items():
    output = '{} ({})\n'.format(word, ','.join([str(page) for page in pages]))
    textFile.write(output)

textFile.close()
pdfFile.close()
print('process ended')
```

and you can finally output the data in the expected format.

Comment: I have observed that this source code (also the original one) is unable to perse some PDF files. I.e. this code doesn't work with all PDF files.

Comment: I had noticed that too, and had supposed that everything went well with the files you were using, as you indicated at the top of your question that the code you provided works for you. I had some problems before with PyPDF2, and you can find some questions on SO from people who had the same problem as you encounter. Maybe you could try some other library with better extraction capabilities, the rest of this code works as intended.